# How to use $a and $b in Perl subroutine

Tags: perl, scope, global-variables, special-variables

I would like to use `$a` and `$b` variables in my anonimous binary functions like it is done in `sort {$a <=> $b} (1, 2, 3)` but I can not figure out why code like

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

Foo::Bar(sub { $a + $b });

package Foo;
sub Bar {
    my ($function) = @_; 

    for my $i (1, 2, 3) {
        local ($a, $b) = ($i, $i);
        print $function->() . "\n";
    }
}
```

does not work. While

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

Foo::Bar(sub { $_ });

package Foo;
sub Bar {
    my ($function) = @_; 

    for my $i (1, 2, 3) {
        local $_ = $i;
        print $function->() . "\n";
    }
}
```

works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$a` and `$b` are special package variables. You're calling `Foo::Bar` from within your `main` package, so you need to set `$main::a` and `$main::b` to get it to work. You can use [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) to get the name of the calling package. This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

Foo::Bar(sub { $a + $b });

package Foo;
sub Bar {
    my ($function) = @_; 
    my $pkg = caller;

    for my $i (1, 2, 3) {
        no strict 'refs';
        local *{ $pkg . '::a' } = \$i;
        local *{ $pkg . '::b' } = \$i;
        print $function->() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, it's OK if you want to create a `sort`-like function that takes a block; but that function should only return values and not `print` stuff, obviously. This is fine as a demonstration though.

Comment: That's true. I suspect the OP doesn't really know what he's doing though, and would be better off with `sub {$_[0] + $_[1]}` and `$function->($i, $i)`.

Comment: Thank you! I think I will use `$_[i]` =) And `$_` is special variable?

Comment: `$_` is special but it's got extra magic on it to make it global everywhere. `$a` and `$b` are slightly less magical.

Comment: `$_` often is implicitly localized though.

Comment: Look at the source for [List::MoreUtils](http://p3rl.org/List::MoreUtils) for some examples in the wild

Comment: In this case, it's actually @_ that you're using. $_[0] is saying "I want scalar element (hence $) number 0 of the array @_".

Comment: I would recommend against using the package of `caller` and instead use the package of the actual function instead or you can get into some trouble down the road.  See [How to make a function that takes a block which requires $a and $b but is in different package than caller in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73515700).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is interested, a copy-and-paste from [List::MoreUtils::PP](https://metacpan.org/source/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428/lib/List/MoreUtils/PP.pm) v.0.428 (as of December 2017):

```
# begin copyrighted content
sub reduce_u(&@)
{
    my $code = shift;

    # Localise $a, $b
    my ($caller_a, $caller_b) = do
    {
        my $pkg = caller();
        no strict 'refs';
        \*{$pkg . '::a'}, \*{$pkg . '::b'};
    };

    local (*$caller_a, *$caller_b);
    *$caller_a = \();
    for (0 .. $#_)
    {
        *$caller_b = \$_[$_];
        *$caller_a = \($code->());
    }

    ${*$caller_a};
}
# end copyrighted content
```

It only differs from the sample above in the area affected by `no strict 'refs';`. Probably can't be done without no strict at all.

Comment: I would recommend against using the package of `caller` and instead use the package of the actual function instead or you can get into some trouble down the road.  See [How to make a function that takes a block which requires $a and $b but is in different package than caller in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73515700).