# How to make a function that takes a block which requires $a and $b but is in different package than caller in perl?

Tags: perl

So I was generating a subroutine that takes a predicate which implicitly creates the `$a` and `$b` variables to be used in that predicate.  Unfortunately, when I started to use classes and used an indirect call to that subroutine, things didn't go according to plan.

I determined that the reason was that the predicate was generated in a different package from the indirect subroutine call, so the `caller` was not the same package as the predicate's package scope.

Here is an example of what I am referring to:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub find(&$\@) {
  my ($pred, $find, $list) = @_;
  my $caller = caller;
  no strict q"refs";
  local *{ "${caller}::a" } = \$find;
  for my $i (0..$#$list) {
    local *{ "${caller}::b" } = \$list->[$i];
    return $i if $pred->();
  }
  return -1;
}

sub indirectFind(&$\@) {
  my ($pred, $find, $list) = @_;
  return find(\&$pred, $find, @$list);
}

package foo;
sub new {
  my ($class) = @_;
  my $self = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
  bless $self, $class;
  return $self;
}
sub find {
  my ($self, $find) = @_;
  return main::find { $a == $b } $find, @$self;
}
sub indirectFind {
  my ($self, $find) = @_;
  return main::indirectFind { $a == $b } $find, @$self;
}

package main;
my $foo = foo->new;
print find { $a == $b } 1, @$foo; # works
print "\n";
print $foo->find(1)."\n";         # works
print $foo->indirectFind(1)."\n"; # does not work
```

How do I get this to work properly, regardless if the call is indirect or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the package associated using a code ref using

```perl
use B qw( svref_2object );

my $pkg = svref_2object( $pred )->STASH->NAME;
```

So,

```perl
use B qw( svref_2object );

sub find(&$@) {
   my $pred = shift;
   my $find = shift;

   my $pkg = svref_2object( $pred )->STASH->NAME;

   my $ap = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{$pkg.'::a'} };  local *$ap = \$find;
   my $bp = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{$pkg.'::b'} };  local *$bp;

   for my $i ( 0 .. $#_ ) {
      *$bp = \( $_[ $i ] );
      return $i if $pred->();
   }

   return -1;
}
```

Comment: That's cool to know about `svref_2object`.  That would be a more direct way of getting the package name, so would be faster I would guess.  I'm unclear as to why you have the `$ap` and `$bp` variables wrapped in a `do` construct.  Is that just to limit the scope of the `no strict 'refs'` to those lines?

Comment: Also would putting the `local` variable declarations external to the loop make it so that the `{$pkg}::$b` wouldn't have to reset the variable every time the loop iterates, increasing the speed ever further?

Comment: @Adrian Yes to both of your questions. The do-block just scopes the pragma. Localizing outside of the loop avoids the unnecessary work of creating a new typeglob and restoring the previous value for each iteration. As far as I can tell, Ikegami's implementation is as optimal as you can be in pure-Perl code on recent versions.

Comment: Agreed @amon, the only thing I don't like about this implementation is that the array is passed  by value rather than by reference, which for large arrays is a downside.

Comment: Yes, the `do` is to limit the scope of the `no strict`. Yes, the `local` is outside the loop to avoid repeatedly localizing and restoring the variable. Also, there's a nice parallel with the previous line.

Comment: Arguments are *always* passed by reference in Perl. The actual difference is that you used to create a reference to an array and pass the reference (by reference). I simply avoid creating the reference and pass the value of the array (by reference). This is just a super quick memcpy of the pointers of the array, and it's *far* more useful this way (cause you can now do `find { ... } f()`).

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying @ikegami, but as I understand it,, though perl does pass the elements by reference, it still needs to construct an array.  Therefore you are actually constructing an array of references. If your array has a lot of elements, that might slow things down depending on how many elements you have in the use case. However, by passing the entire array as a reference, you wouldn't need to construct such a large array. As for your example, are you saying that you can pass an empty array? Might be more useful in some cases, but not necessarily. Depends on array size.

Comment: As I already said, it's a simple `memcpy`. We're talking about a single CPU instruction. Long lists don't take appreciably longer.  /// Re "*are you saying that you can pass an empty array?*",  You can't pass arrays to subs, just scalars. And while I didn't say it, you can indeed past no scalars beyond `$pred` and `$find`. /// Re "*Might be more useful in some cases, but not necessarily.*" It's hugely useful quite regularly.   .... Actually, no, since you're returning an index. You gotta have an array for that to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to get the package name of the function that is being called so that the variables `$a` and `$b` can be injected into that package.

Replacing the original `find` subroutine:

```perl
# use Sub::Util qw( subname ); # less direct way to get package name
use B qw( svref_2object );     # more direct way to get package name
sub find(&$\@) {
  my ($pred, $find, $list) = @_;
  # get the package that &$pred belongs to
  # my ($pkg) = subname($pred) =~ /^(.+)::/;     # less direct
  my $pkg = svref_2object( $pred )->STASH->NAME; # more direct
  no strict q"refs";
  local *{ "${pkg}::a" } = \$find;
  for my $i (0..$#$list) {
    local *{ "${pkg}::b" } = \$list->[$i];
    return $i if $pred->();
  }
  return -1;
}
```

The calls will now all work.

```perl
package main;
my $foo = foo->new;
print find { $a == $b } 1, @$foo; # works
print "\n";
print $foo->find(1)."\n";         # works
print $foo->indirectFind(1)."\n"; # works
```

Comment: The Sub::Util documentation suggests the regex `my ($pkg) = (subname $pred) =~ m/^(.+)::.*?$/ ` for extracting the package name, which handles `Nested::Packages` correctly.

Comment: Good to know @amon.  But wouldn't regex `m/^(.+)::/` work just as well as `m/^(.+)::.*?$/`?

Comment: Yes, good point. I took the regex from the docs without thinking to much. In the original, there was a capture group for the trailing sub name, but of course that part of the pattern can be removed entirely here.